# Google Map Dyanamic language change

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using backbone.js for one of my project, and I am using Google map api version 3. Depending on some ajax response I want to change Google map language on the fly. Is there any ways of doing it.Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to say by 'change Google map language'?

Comment: I want to do Google map localization, I mean to load Google map in different languages like thai, chinese etc..

Comment: check my answer below. It work fine, I tested it!

Comment: so, did you get over this?

Comment: Had the same problem and sabotero's resolution to dynamically inject the library helped but it did not reload the map. as refreshing the entire page was not an option, so after doing the above, I've placed a timeout after which I've nullified the map var and then ran again the code that inits the map var.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following example where I'm using a button but you can call the `ChangeGoogleMapsLanguage` from your callback with the parameters you want (adapting the code to take `lang` parameter):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Asynchronous Loading</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                mapOptions);
        }

        function loadScript(lang) {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' +
                'callback=initialize';
            if (lang) {
                script.src += '&language=' + lang;
            }

            script.id = "google-maps-script";
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }

        window.onload = loadScript;

        function ChangeGoogleMapsLanguage() {

            var lang = document.getElementById('language').value,
                oldScript = document.getElementById("google-maps-script");
            oldScript.parentNode.removeChild(oldScript);

            delete google.maps;

            loadScript(lang);
        }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="language" value="ja" />
    <button id="localization-button" onclick="ChangeGoogleMapsLanguage()">Change Language</button>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Working in jsFiddle as well: [Exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/2AKqM/)

NOTE: I'm using vanilla JavaScript. The code might work fine in Chrome, I did not teste it in other browsers.

Comment: Have you found another way to do this without need to reconnect google maps script again?

Comment: will it cause this error "You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors." . I am having this issue. any  suggestions?

Comment: you have to remove the old script tag as done in the example.