# Google Map reverse geo-coding webservice setting language

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I am trying to get the address from a pair of lat and lng. I am doing it by

```js
new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode({ 'latLng': latLng}, function (results, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
     //code to get details from address_components
   }
});
```

it is working properly. But if i change browser language the address components come in the selected locale. I don't want that. I need the address in English only. I am using the following code to achieve this. But its not working. I am getting the address in the selected language only.

```js
new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode({ 'latLng': latLng, 'language' :'en'}, function (results, status) {
               if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  }
});
```

Please tell me what i am missing in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried before and I think all you need is add `language` into your `<script>` tag for Google map:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=false&libraries=places&language=en-US"></script>
```

Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090711/google-map-dyanamic-language-change) I think it will help you. Before you call `geocode`function, you change the language first. And after that, change back to default:

```
function loadScript(lang) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' +
                'callback=initialize';
    if (lang) {
        script.src += '&language=' + lang;
    }

    script.id = "google-maps-script";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it is working. But i think it will apply for all the apis.If i want to do it only for the api in my question, is there any way to do it?

Comment: I have updated answer with SO answer about change language. Hope this help!