# jQuery - How to save jQuery block of code in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery Code, see below please.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('select').on('change', function () {
      var test = this.value;
      console.log(test);
    })

});
```

which is working perfectly.

Now what I would like to do is, I want to save this code as a **function** so I can use it somewhere else. Can you help me please?

**update**

[image]

as you can see on the photo, there is a dropdownlist.

```
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
key=MYAPIKEY&
callback=initAutocomplete

&language=fr"
```

what I want to update is, whenever I choose the language from the dropdownlist the src attribute should get updated. In the src attribute you can see the value and in that value the last parameter is language.

I want to update the **language** parameter according to the dropdownlist.

Comment: Which code do you want to save ? The action after the event or the eventListener + action ?

Comment: Shows little to no research effort. See here for some basics of [**JavaScript Function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) - Ones you know how to create a function add the code you wish to call again into it and call as needed.

Comment: Have a look at the answer in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090711/google-map-dyanamic-language-change sort of doing a similar thing.  However, I would probably recommend reloading the page as loading multiple scripts may cause issues (I have't tried it but I know when you reload some scripts you will get conflicting variables)

Comment: I see that you have added a completely new question in the update. This invalidates the comments and the answers provided. Please add a new question instead of updating this.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function like this:

```
function onChange() {
  var test = this.value;
  console.log(test);
});
```

Then, use that function as the change event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('select').on('change', onChange);
});
```

Now you can reuse this `function` for any event handler.

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple answer to store what you've done.

You can just store your action into a function, or you can create and attach the result action function into one function.

```js
$(".my-select").on("change",function(){
  actionAfterChange($(this).val())
});

//Just action
function actionAfterChange(value){
  console.log("function actionAfterChange > ",value)
}

//Create event listener and attach a function
function attachEventAndAction(element,event,action){
   $(element).on(event,function(){
      action($(this).val())
   });
}


attachEventAndAction(".my-select2","change",actionAfterChange)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="my-select">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="my-select2">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```